# How can my aiml interpreter in Android get to know the ' é ' character?

Tags: android, aiml, pandorabots

I created a chatbot with aiml in pandorabots having French as a language. Then I bought an API so I can implement it in an android application. But it doesn't recognize some words having an "é" in the pattern.
How can my aiml interpreter in Android get to know the ' é ' character ?

I tried to predict words with the same meaning and use the srai category but still not a solution

Answer (score 0):

If you write your categories with `e` instead of `é` and add this to your normal.substitution file:

```
["é","e"],
```

It should work

```
<category>
    <pattern>Beyonce</pattern>
    <template>
         Beyonce is a great singer.
    </template>
</category>
```

It can now respond to something like Beyoncé, as well as Beyonce

[image]

Comment: On PandoraBots it works, but when I write a word with 'é' in my Android application, I guess the interpreter of the API change the special character in a format other than a sample 'e'

Comment: You need to find what that "e" is and add it to your normal.substitution file.